# Duda sobre flexbox Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Tengo un problema con Bootstrap y es que pongo una imagen dentro de una etiqueta div, y creí que usando flexbox(la clase justify-content-center) podía centrarla verticalmente pero sigue igual en la parte izquierda. Quisera saber cual es la razon por el que no se centra horizontalmente.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Template bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <style>
        .img-portafolio-cards{
        height: 15.5rem;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="bg-warning m-3 justify-content-center">
                    <img src="https://us.123rf.com/450wm/phoebeyu/phoebeyu1612/phoebeyu161201619/67395759-fondo-de-l%C3%ADnea-cuadrada-de-geometr%C3%ADa-enrejado-de-tracer%C3%ADa-de-ventana-chino-incons%C3%BAtil-.jpg?ver=6" alt="..." class=" img-portafolio-cards img-responsive rounded-circle">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="bg-warning m-3 justify-content-center">
                    <img src="https://us.123rf.com/450wm/phoebeyu/phoebeyu1612/phoebeyu161201619/67395759-fondo-de-l%C3%ADnea-cuadrada-de-geometr%C3%ADa-enrejado-de-tracer%C3%ADa-de-ventana-chino-incons%C3%BAtil-.jpg?ver=6"alt="..." class=" img-portafolio-cards img-responsive rounded-circle">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="bg-warning m-3 justify-content-center">
                    <img src="https://us.123rf.com/450wm/phoebeyu/phoebeyu1612/phoebeyu161201619/67395759-fondo-de-l%C3%ADnea-cuadrada-de-geometr%C3%ADa-enrejado-de-tracer%C3%ADa-de-ventana-chino-incons%C3%BAtil-.jpg?ver=6"alt="..." class=" img-portafolio-cards img-responsive rounded-circle">
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No te está funcionando porque para hacer uso de la propiedad `justify-content` el elemento debe tener `display: flex` y en tu caso no lo tiene. Añadiendo al contenedor de la imagen la clase `d-flex` te debería de funcionar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Template bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <style>
        .img-portafolio-cards{
        height: 15.5rem;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="bg-warning m-3 justify-content-center d-flex">
                    <img src="https://us.123rf.com/450wm/phoebeyu/phoebeyu1612/phoebeyu161201619/67395759-fondo-de-l%C3%ADnea-cuadrada-de-geometr%C3%ADa-enrejado-de-tracer%C3%ADa-de-ventana-chino-incons%C3%BAtil-.jpg?ver=6" alt="..." class=" img-portafolio-cards img-responsive rounded-circle">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="bg-warning m-3 justify-content-center d-flex">
                    <img src="https://us.123rf.com/450wm/phoebeyu/phoebeyu1612/phoebeyu161201619/67395759-fondo-de-l%C3%ADnea-cuadrada-de-geometr%C3%ADa-enrejado-de-tracer%C3%ADa-de-ventana-chino-incons%C3%BAtil-.jpg?ver=6"alt="..." class=" img-portafolio-cards img-responsive rounded-circle">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="bg-warning m-3 justify-content-center d-flex">
                    <img src="https://us.123rf.com/450wm/phoebeyu/phoebeyu1612/phoebeyu161201619/67395759-fondo-de-l%C3%ADnea-cuadrada-de-geometr%C3%ADa-enrejado-de-tracer%C3%ADa-de-ventana-chino-incons%C3%BAtil-.jpg?ver=6"alt="..." class=" img-portafolio-cards img-responsive rounded-circle">
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```